# Differences between compiler and ast module in python

Tags: python

The compiler module has been deprecated in python 2.6.
Does anybody know what is the reason behind the deprecation ?
Is the ast module a direct replacement ? Will the ast module be supported in python 3k ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `compiler` module was a Python compiler written in Python. It was horribly slow and a pain to maintain.

The `ast` module is a smarter solution to the same problem: it provides Python level access to the *actual* compiler used when importing modules. Since it is just a visible API for the builtin compiler, it isn't going anywhere.

`ast` isn't a drop-in replacement for `compiler` (i.e. the APIs are different), but it certainly covers many of the same use cases.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) module replaces the [`compiler`](http://docs.python.org/library/compiler.html) module. And what do you mean by "will be supported"? Python 3 has been out for years, and of course [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ast.html) is part of its standard library.

Reasons for the removal can be found [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007615.html).